# Simple foreach loop help needed in wordpress "the loop"

Tags: loop, php

I need a foreach loop inside "the loop"

**This is my current code (index.php) :**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  title="<?php get_the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<div><a data-backdrop="true" data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" href="#">Show tags</a></div>
<div id="modal-from-dom">Popup contents goes here (tags) </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It lists post title and tags in the index php. I display all my tags in a pop up box. User should click "show tags" link to view the tags.

Popup doesn't work correctly when i have more than 1 post. Because i need a unique name for each popup.

I mean instead of "modal-from-dom" for all i need like "modal-from-dom-1,modal-from-dom-2,etc"

I tried the following code but its not working.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<?php $modalcount = 1; ?> 
    <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  title="<?php get_the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <div><a data-backdrop="true" data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom-<?php echo $modalcount; ?>" href="#">Show tags</a></div>
    <div id="modal-from-dom-<?php echo $modalcount; ?>">Popup contents goes here (tags) </div>
<?php $modalcount++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `the_ID()` which will always be unique and won't require any extra code to be used.

Comment: Wonderful solution. worked like a charm. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because you define modalcount inside the WordPress 'while' loop - put that before

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

and it should work perfectly.

Edit: so what you want is:

```
<?php $modalcount = 1; ?> 
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
    <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  title="<?php get_the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <div><a data-backdrop="true" data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom-<?php echo $modalcount; ?>" href="#">Show tags</a></div>
    <div id="modal-from-dom-<?php echo $modalcount; ?>">Popup contents goes here (tags) </div>
<?php $modalcount++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```